# Having problems plotting a partly undefined function

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib

I have an assignment for my Applied Computer Science class in which we are to test the strength and qualities of an algorithm that tries to find the k:th highest value in a list. This is to be tested both for varying k:s (0, 1, 2, ..., k=N), and varying N:s where I have chosen k=0 and N (1, 2, ..., N). We're supposed to determine whether the algorithm ever makes more than pi*N comparisons as well as log2(N/2 - k)*N comparisons.

To find some clarity in this I made two plots, both having number of comparisons as the y-axis, and k and N respectively for the x-axis. Alongside the plots I want the functions y = pi*N and y = log2(N/2 - k)*N. The problem is I get a ValueError for the second function, most definitely when N/2 = k. I would still like to plot it in python and my question is how to get around this.

The rest of the code isn't really relevant. 
My question is: how can I plot this function while circumventing it's undefined parts? I still want to illustrate the undefined part so I don't want to make exceptions in which a simplification is made.

```
def plotHelper(x, yA, yS, title, trials):

    yPi = list()
    yLogN = list()

    for point in x:
        yPi.append(point*math.pi)
        yLogN.append((trials*math.log(trials/2 - point, 2)


    plt.figure()
    plt.title(title)

    plt.plot(x, yA)
    plt.plot(x, yS)
    plt.plot(x, yPi)
    plt.plot(x, yLogN)

    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend(["Mean", "Standard Deviation", "y = pi * N"])
    plt.ylabel("Comparisons")
    plt.xlabel("k")
    plt.show()

def plot():
    choice = initiate()
    yA, yS, trials = trialFunc(choice)
    x = range(0, trials)
    f_of_k = "Comparisons as a function of desired k (N elements)"
    f_of_n = "Comparisons as a function of elements (k = 0)"

    if choice:
        title = f_of_k
    else:
        title = f_of_n

plotHelper(x, yA, yS, title, trials)
```

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DannyData Did you copy your code in exactly the way it looks in your file? Indentation is important, and this code will not work properly unless the `plotHelper` and `plot` function bodies are indented, as you see from David's edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot represent a value of a function as a number, you can represent it as a Not-a-Number aka NaN. There's no ready-made constant for it, but you can easily produce that value:

```
NaN = float('NaN')
```

Now your function can go like this:

```
def function_to_plot(n):  # A contrived example.
  if abs(n) <= 1:
    return NaN
  return sqrt(n * n - sin(n) ** 2)
```

After that, [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/) just works, it knows how to skip points that are NaNs.

If you just want to tabulate your function by hand, you can safely print NaNs using format for floats.

For a bit more detail, you can use `float('+inf')` and `float('-inf')` to represent infinities.
Also, just in case, Python works fine with complex numbers; `import cmath` and do things like `assert cmath.sqrt(-2j) == (1-1j)`.

Comment: Another option could be to use `np.nan` instead of defining your own constant

Comment: ^ This is fair, but assumes `numpy` which the question does not mention.

Comment: True. But since it will be imported in `matplotlib` anyway, it must be installed and available for use, even if it means adding an extra import to the code. Just my 2¢

Comment: Hmm okay. I tried implementing it sort of the way you described. It seems to handle the NaN parts yet it's not plotting it like I thought. 

    def plotHelper(x, yA, yS, title, trials):

        yPi = list()
        yLogN = list()
        NaN = float('NaN')
    
        for point in x:
            yPi.append(point*math.pi)
            try:
                yLogN.append(trials*(math.log(abs(trials/2 - point), 2)))
            except ValueError:
                yLogN.append(NaN)

I tried the way you described using a function but I still got ValueError.

Comment: Not sure how I add images but when plotting the function it starts at x=0, y=1000 but it should be starting at 1*log2(1/2 - 0)ish.

Comment: I realize it should have been point * log.... not trials * log.... 
So it's all good, thank you everyone!